# How to tell ffmpeg to loop through all files in directory in order

Tags: linux, bash, loops, ffmpeg

ffmpeg has concat option for this but all streams start working really bad and breaking sound after a day of streaming.

I tried looking at loops but i couldnt figure out how to execute a loop with ffmpeg command so it transcodes all files in 1 directory

/lely/ffmpeg -y -re -i /home/ftp/kid1.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -dts_delta_threshold 1000 -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv rtmp://10.0.0.17:1935/live/kid

In folder /home/ftp/ there are files kid1, kid2, kid3 - all *.mp4 files

So basically i would like a loop to change the input to next file every time previous ends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you could use `find` and `xargs` to help you feed the files for `ffmpeg`:

```
find /home/ftp -name "*.mp4" | xargs -I $ /lely/ffmpeg -y -re -i $ -vcodec copy -acodec copy -dts_delta_threshold 1000 -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv rtmp://10.0.0.17:1935/live/kid
```

Here you first ask `find` to look for all mp3 files in /home/ftp.

Then you feed the results to `xargs`. For xargs you tell it to replace input it receives with token `$` in your `ffmpeg` string.

Comment: That worked, thank you. But it doesnt start from the first file for some reason?

Comment: Add a suitable `sort` command after find pipe and xargs. Something like this `find | sort | xargs`. You can check `sort` parameters for desired sort type.. If it helps, please vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the video files to a "named pipe" and use the pipe as a source for ffmpeg. 
For example:

```
    mkfifo pipeFile            # create a FIFO file (named pipe)
    cat $(find /home/ftp -name "*.mp4") > pipeFile &  # concatenate video files do the pipe (do not forget the "&" for running in background)
    /lely/ffmpeg -y -re -i pipeFile -vcodec copy -acodec copy -dts_delta_threshold 1000 -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv rtmp://10.0.0.17:1935/live/kid  # run ffmpeg with the pipe as the input
```

Notes:

1. The order of files in the input will be that the find generates. You can add a "sort" command after the find to produce files in a sorted manner.
2. I have not tested this, since a I do not have ffmpeg installed. However, it should work :-)